# Send a JSON request to a server with httpclientcomponents

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

This Code Works Correctly...Because I had a lot search for this I decide to put this code for who want to send a json request to a server with a URL
.This is [HttpClientComponent](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1)

```
public static boolean sendJsonTo(String URL,JSONObject jo) throws IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient= HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    try {

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(jo.toString());
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(request);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
        // handle exception here
    } finally {
        httpClient.close();
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm using [this json version](http://ttp://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20151123)

and This is sample code for make json Object

```
public static JSONObject test(String firstname,String lastname){
    JSONObject jup=new JSONObject();
    jup.put("fname",firstname);
    jup.put("lname",lastname);
    return jup;
}
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: In The Client Side>>HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error @Jan

Comment: And the Server log for that?

Comment: excuse me my friend... I'm coming now ..wait

Comment: excuse me ..can you say for me what requets.setEntity() and getEntity do?

Comment: I Think The problem is by them@Jan

Comment: they set the data to be send with the post. The server in your case needs to accept application/json as content and could then read data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99047/discussion-between-meer-and-jan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle Response From Server:
Try this:

```
HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Or like this

```
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    JsonFactory jsonf = new JsonFactory();

    // try with resource is not strictly necessary here 
    // but is a good practice
    try(InputStream instream = entity.getContent()) {            JsonParser jsonParser = jsonf.createParser(instream);
        // Use the parser to deserialize the object from the content stream
        return stuff;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks my friend @Jan

Comment: May I have discussion with you?? @Jan

Comment: Seen your edits in chat - file upload might best be done differently (not endoded as json at all) - try searching fileuploadb httpclient on this site